# Beamer Customization - Add textual sidebar and adjust title

Tags: beamer, positioning, themes, tikz-positioning, customize

I would like to customize a presentation that already exists.

The first 3 slides would be standard. And the perosanilization would happen from the 4th slide onwards.

```
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
%%                          PREÂMBULO
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % codificacao de caracteres
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % codificacao de fontes
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}                  % idioma
\usepackage[brazil=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst} % Não separar as palavras
\hyphenation{thatshouldnot}         % Não separar as palavras

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}              % tema
\usecolortheme{orchid}              % cores
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}      % fonte modo matematico

%% --------------------------------------
%%              PACOTES
%% --------------------------------------

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,labelsep=none]{subfig}

\usepackage[skip=6pt]{caption} % example skip set to 2pt
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}   %%% diminuir o tamanho da legenda nas fig e tabelas


\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\usepackage{draftwatermark} % Marca D'Agua

\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}      % grafico (caixas)
\usepackage{epstopdf}               % converter a figura

\usepackage{tikz}                   % grafico potentes
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees, shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}   %% p/colchetes
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}


\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} %% p/colchetes

\usepackage{epsfig}                 % for figures
\usepackage{xcolor}                 % for color

\usepackage{color,colortbl,multirow}    % tabelas e matrizes
\usepackage{fix2col}                    % fixa algumas perdas causado p/ uso de 2 colunas
\usepackage{multicol}                   % documento com multiplas colunas
\setlength{\columnsep}{.15cm}

\usepackage{hyperref}                   % links e referencias 

\usepackage{setspace}                   % controlar o espaçamento entre linhas
\usepackage{ragged2e}                   % justificar texto
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}      % Permitir argumentos opcionais após a moldura.
\apptocmd{\column}{}{\justifying}{}

\usepackage{textpos} 
\usepackage{marvosym} % \MVRIGHTarrow
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % \shortrightarrow
\usepackage{textcomp} % \textrightarrow




%%%% --------------------------------
%%% REDUZIR MARGENS NO TCOLORBOX

\newlength{\marginwidth}
\setlength{\marginwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\marginwidth}{-\textwidth}

%%%% --------------------------------


%% -------------- Tabelas -------------- %%
\usepackage{ltxtable}           % Fornece a funcionalidade de longtable e tabularx 
\usepackage{booktabs}           % Melhora a Qualidade das Tabelas
\usepackage{tabularx}           % Tabelas
\usepackage{longtable}          % Tabelas Longas
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}   
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  

\usepackage{bigstrut} 
\usepackage{ltablex}


\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%% --------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{enumerate}          % controla o estilo de enumeração
\defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{\insertdescriptionitem\hfill}


\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[circle]

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[square]

\setbeamercolor*{enumerate item}{fg=ao(english)}
\setbeamercolor*{enumerate subitem}{fg=bostonuniversityred}
\setbeamercolor*{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=gray}

\setbeamercolor*{description item}{fg=ao(english)}

\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=green!40!black} % mudar a cor do itemize

\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\justifying} %% Justificar os Itens (Itemize)

%% Mudar Estilo das Sections do Sumário
\setbeamerfont{section number projected}{%
  family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size=\normalsize}
\setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=ao(english),fg=white}


%% --------------------------------------------------------


\usepackage{latexsym}                   % Adicionar Simbolos
\usepackage{pifont}                     % simbolos diferentes | circulos c/ numrs no seu interior, letras gregas, Zapf Dingbats // Exemplo: http://www.uel.br/projetos/matessencial/superior/pdfs/latexmat.pdf (pág 38)

\usepackage{amsmath}                    % pacotes matematicos 
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   % pacotes matematicos 
\usepackage{amssymb}                    % pacotes matematicos | simbolos
\usepackage{amsthm}                     % pacotes matematicos | teoremas e similares
\usepackage{exscale}                    % pacotes matematicos 
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}




%% --------------------------------------
%%    Blocos \TCOLOBLOCKS
%% --------------------------------------

\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}




%% --------------------------------------
%%    Blocos \SMARTDIAGRAM
%% --------------------------------------

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

%% --------------------------------------
%%          SIMBOLOS
%% --------------------------------------

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}


%% --------------------------------------
%%          SQL ||  CODE
%% --------------------------------------
\newtcbox{\myovalbox}{colback=gray!10!white,boxrule=0pt,arc=5pt,
    boxsep=0pt,left=3pt,right=3pt,top=3pt,bottom=3pt}

\definecolor{brightpink}{rgb}{1.0, 0.0, 0.5}

\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}


\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    language=SQL,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{magenta},
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue}\bfseries,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

%%%% -------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{americanrose}{rgb}{1.0, 0.01, 0.24}

\colorlet{codecolor}{black!25}
\newcommand{\codebox}[1]{%
\colorbox{codecolor}{\ttfamily \color{americanrose} \detokenize{#1}}%
}


%% --------------------------------------
%%    PERSONALIZAR CORES
%% --------------------------------------

\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{bostonuniversityred}{rgb}{0.8, 0.0, 0.0}


\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=ao(english)}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=bostonuniversityred}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}

\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=bostonuniversityred,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=black,bg=white}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=structure!75,fg=black, bg=white}

%% --------------------------------------
%%              LOGOMARCA
%% --------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle%
    \vphantom{g}% To avoid fluctuations per frame
    %\hrule% Uncomment to see desired effect, without a full-width hrule
    \par% <-- added
    \hspace*{-\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth-0.5\textwidth}% <-- calculation of left margin width
    \rule[0.3\baselineskip]{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}%
}
  
%% --------------------------------------
\setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{}

%\useoutertheme{miniframes} % faixa preta personalizavel acima
%\useinnertheme{circles}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % remover botão e links

%% --------------------------------------
%%   Remover Faculdade do Lado do Nome no Rodapé
%% --------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor%~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother




%% --------------------------------------
%%    TITULO
%% --------------------------------------

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Large}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\footnotesize}



% position the logo
\title[\sc{Class}]{\textbf{Chapter Theme - Lecture}}
\subtitle{Specific Class Theme}
\author[Name Tecaher]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{example-image-a} }
\institute{\textbf{Teacher's name}} 
\date{06 de junho de 2022}



%%  =============================================================
%%                      INICIO  DA  APRESENTAÇÃO
%%  =============================================================

\begin{document}

%% -----------------------------------------------------------------
%%                              CAPA
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------

 \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
  \titlepage
 \end{frame}


%% --------------------------------------
%%    LOGOMARCA NO TÍTULO DOS SLIDES
%% --------------------------------------
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{1cm}(\textwidth,-1.05cm)
      \hspace{-1.5cm}  \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{example-image-b} 
\end{textblock*}}


%% ==============================================================================
%%                                  SLIDES
%% ==============================================================================


%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%                              FOLHA DE DADOS
%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Presentment}

\vspace{-.25cm}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{7.85cm}

%%% --------------
\begin{block}{Discipline}
specific data,  \\
teacher email   \\
Name            \\
Between others  \\ \vspace{.25cm}
\faGraduationCap  \\ \vspace{0.75mm}
\faEnvelopeSquare 
\end{block}
%%% --------------


%%% --------------
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!15!white,colframe=ao(english),title=\textbf{Class 22}]
\large{\color{red}{\textbf{Specific Class Theme}}}
\end{tcolorbox}
%%% --------------



\end{column}

%%% ------------------------
%%% ------------------------

\begin{column}{4.35cm}

%%% --------------
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{example-image-c} 
\end{figure}
%%% --------------

\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}



%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%%                          TÓPICOS DA AULA
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Table Of Contents}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{9.25cm}

%%% ------------------------

\vspace{-.25cm}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,if odd page*={colback=yellow!50}{colback=red!50}]

\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}
\tcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}{blanker,
before skip=6pt,after skip=6pt,
borderline west={3mm}{0pt}{red}}

\textbf{\color{red}{\Large Guide}} \\

\begin{myitemize}
    \item       
\end{myitemize}

%Some Text.
\end{tcolorbox}
%%% ------------------------

\end{column}

%%% ------------------------
%%% ------------------------

\begin{column}{5.5cm}

\vspace{-.30cm}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{example-image-c} 
\end{figure}

\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}




%% ==============================================================================
%%                          SLIDES   C/   CONTEÚDO
%% ==============================================================================


\begin{frame}{Introduction}


\end{frame}





%%  =============================================================
\end{document}
```

Code result:

[image: Slide 01]

[image: Slide 02]

[image: Slide 03]

**I would like the 04 slide onwards, to maintain a pattern with a side text, as I try to show below:**

[image: Slide 4]

**I would also like to know how to interrupt the sideband, because I don't want it to come out in the bibliography.**

Well my doubts are here, I thank you in advance for your attention, I look forward for the answers.

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sidebar and cancel it for the frames which shouldn't have it:

```
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
%%                          PREÂMBULO
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[width=1cm]{sidebar}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{\vspace{3cm}\hspace{0.2cm}\rotatebox{90}{\Large Some Text}}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar left}{bg=green}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % codificacao de caracteres
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % codificacao de fontes
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}                  % idioma
\usepackage[brazil=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst} % Não separar as palavras
\hyphenation{thatshouldnot}         % Não separar as palavras

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}              % tema
\usecolortheme{orchid}              % cores
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}      % fonte modo matematico

%% --------------------------------------
%%              PACOTES
%% --------------------------------------

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,labelsep=none]{subfig}

\usepackage[skip=6pt]{caption} % example skip set to 2pt
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}   %%% diminuir o tamanho da legenda nas fig e tabelas


\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\usepackage{draftwatermark} % Marca D'Agua

\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}      % grafico (caixas)
\usepackage{epstopdf}               % converter a figura

\usepackage{tikz}                   % grafico potentes
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees, shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}   %% p/colchetes
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}


\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} %% p/colchetes

\usepackage{epsfig}                 % for figures
\usepackage{xcolor}                 % for color

\usepackage{color,colortbl,multirow}    % tabelas e matrizes
\usepackage{fix2col}                    % fixa algumas perdas causado p/ uso de 2 colunas
\usepackage{multicol}                   % documento com multiplas colunas
\setlength{\columnsep}{.15cm}

\usepackage{hyperref}                   % links e referencias 

\usepackage{setspace}                   % controlar o espaçamento entre linhas
\usepackage{ragged2e}                   % justificar texto
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}      % Permitir argumentos opcionais após a moldura.
\apptocmd{\column}{}{\justifying}{}

\usepackage{textpos} 
\usepackage{marvosym} % \MVRIGHTarrow
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % \shortrightarrow
\usepackage{textcomp} % \textrightarrow




%%%% --------------------------------
%%% REDUZIR MARGENS NO TCOLORBOX

\newlength{\marginwidth}
\setlength{\marginwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\marginwidth}{-\textwidth}

%%%% --------------------------------


%% -------------- Tabelas -------------- %%
\usepackage{ltxtable}           % Fornece a funcionalidade de longtable e tabularx 
\usepackage{booktabs}           % Melhora a Qualidade das Tabelas
\usepackage{tabularx}           % Tabelas
\usepackage{longtable}          % Tabelas Longas
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}   
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  

\usepackage{bigstrut} 
\usepackage{ltablex}


\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%% --------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{enumerate}          % controla o estilo de enumeração
\defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{\insertdescriptionitem\hfill}


\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[circle]

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[square]

\setbeamercolor*{enumerate item}{fg=ao(english)}
\setbeamercolor*{enumerate subitem}{fg=bostonuniversityred}
\setbeamercolor*{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=gray}

\setbeamercolor*{description item}{fg=ao(english)}

\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=green!40!black} % mudar a cor do itemize

\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\justifying} %% Justificar os Itens (Itemize)

%% Mudar Estilo das Sections do Sumário
\setbeamerfont{section number projected}{%
  family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size=\normalsize}
\setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=ao(english),fg=white}


%% --------------------------------------------------------


\usepackage{latexsym}                   % Adicionar Simbolos
\usepackage{pifont}                     % simbolos diferentes | circulos c/ numrs no seu interior, letras gregas, Zapf Dingbats // Exemplo: http://www.uel.br/projetos/matessencial/superior/pdfs/latexmat.pdf (pág 38)

\usepackage{amsmath}                    % pacotes matematicos 
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   % pacotes matematicos 
\usepackage{amssymb}                    % pacotes matematicos | simbolos
\usepackage{amsthm}                     % pacotes matematicos | teoremas e similares
\usepackage{exscale}                    % pacotes matematicos 
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}




%% --------------------------------------
%%    Blocos \TCOLOBLOCKS
%% --------------------------------------

\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}




%% --------------------------------------
%%    Blocos \SMARTDIAGRAM
%% --------------------------------------

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

%% --------------------------------------
%%          SIMBOLOS
%% --------------------------------------

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}


%% --------------------------------------
%%          SQL ||  CODE
%% --------------------------------------
\newtcbox{\myovalbox}{colback=gray!10!white,boxrule=0pt,arc=5pt,
    boxsep=0pt,left=3pt,right=3pt,top=3pt,bottom=3pt}

\definecolor{brightpink}{rgb}{1.0, 0.0, 0.5}

\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}


\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    language=SQL,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{magenta},
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue}\bfseries,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

%%%% -------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{americanrose}{rgb}{1.0, 0.01, 0.24}

\colorlet{codecolor}{black!25}
\newcommand{\codebox}[1]{%
\colorbox{codecolor}{\ttfamily \color{americanrose} \detokenize{#1}}%
}


%% --------------------------------------
%%    PERSONALIZAR CORES
%% --------------------------------------

\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{bostonuniversityred}{rgb}{0.8, 0.0, 0.0}


\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=ao(english)}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=bostonuniversityred}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}

\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=bostonuniversityred,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=black,bg=white}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=structure!75,fg=black, bg=white}

%% --------------------------------------
%%              LOGOMARCA
%% --------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle%
    \vphantom{g}% To avoid fluctuations per frame
    %\hrule% Uncomment to see desired effect, without a full-width hrule
    \par% <-- added
    \hspace*{-\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth-0.5\textwidth}% <-- calculation of left margin width
    \rule[0.3\baselineskip]{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}%
}
  
%% --------------------------------------
\setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{}

%\useoutertheme{miniframes} % faixa preta personalizavel acima
%\useinnertheme{circles}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % remover botão e links

%% --------------------------------------
%%   Remover Faculdade do Lado do Nome no Rodapé
%% --------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor%~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother




%% --------------------------------------
%%    TITULO
%% --------------------------------------

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Large}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\footnotesize}



% position the logo
\title[\sc{Class}]{\textbf{Chapter Theme - Lecture}}
\subtitle{Specific Class Theme}
\author[Name Tecaher]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{example-image-a} }
\institute{\textbf{Teacher's name}} 
\date{06 de junho de 2022}



%%  =============================================================
%%                      INICIO  DA  APRESENTAÇÃO
%%  =============================================================


\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{}
\begin{frame}
frame 1
\end{frame}
}


\begin{frame}
frame 2
\end{frame}

{
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{}
\begin{frame}
frame 3
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]